# no route to host when mounting CIFS share

Tags: networking, server, samba

We have two ubuntu machines running docker + kubernetes and they need to access a windows share.

The first one is setup in /etc/fstab :

> //dfs/Archive01 /mnt/dfs cifs rw,cred=/etc/cifspasswd,forceuid,forcegid 0 1

And it works, after executing mount -a we can get to the directories.

But doing the same config on machine 2 we get the dreaded "no route to host" error when trying to mount.

> ping dfs

comes back with an ip-address so that works.

ip -4 addr show on the machine that's working shows:

1. ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
   altname enp3s0
   inet 10.203.32.80/24 brd 10.203.32.255 scope global ens160
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2. docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
   inet 10.200.200.20/24 scope global docker0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3. vxlan.calico: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
   inet 10.244.255.192/32 scope global vxlan.calico
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

And on the failing machine ip -4 a says:

1. ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
   altname enp3s0
   inet 10.203.32.81/24 brd 10.203.32.255 scope global ens160
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2. docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
   inet 10.200.200.21/24 brd 10.200.200.255 scope global docker0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3. vxlan.calico: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
   inet 10.244.161.0/32 scope global vxlan.calico
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

dmesg says:

> CIFS: Unable to determine destination address

No clue why it's failing on the 2nd and working on the 1st. Got a feeling it has to do with the calico networks but not sure how to debug.

Anyone knows how to fix this or at least where to check?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Found the solution.

Forgot to install cifs-utils and keyutils on the second machine.

so just doing

```
sudo apt-get install keyutils 

sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

fixed it

Comment: the second one worked for me

Comment: this also works for centos/rocky 8. The packages are named the same too.

Comment: In case any RHEL users happen across this in google search like I did, the equiv RHEL packages are installed with `sudo yum install keyutils cifs-utils`

Answer (score 1):

I had this, couldn´t connect to my Synology NAS anymore after upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.
Apparently the upgrade had uninstalled smbclient (or else it worked without it in 20.04, not certain), cifs-utils was still installed.

Now I had to add

- keyutils (per Serve's answer, haven't tested if it is necessary)
- smbclient
- I installed winbind as well because apt suggested it,
  but not necessary (only for Windows domain logon). It can come in handy to connect to my laptop or the company network, but so far I'm not using it yet.

That changed it to a different error message (operation not supported) for which I had to add option `vers=2.0` to the relevant lines in /etc/fstab.

-- Edit --
Checking my NAS, I found that it was set to maximum version = 2.0. Changed that and removed the 'vers=2.0' from /etc/fstab, and it works. Apparently auto-negotiating the protocol version doesn´t work too good when you set a maximum on Synology.

Comment: why not vers=3.11? or did you use that and needed to back to 2?

Comment: @Serve - The default is to negotiate the lowest common version >2. The error "operation not supported" is an indication that Synology doesn´t support what negotiation found. Some Googling pointed me to someone somewhere who said you must specify 2.0, and that turned out to work. I didn´t try 3.0 or 3.11, assuming that would just make the non-working version explicit.

Comment: 10 minutes later - checked my NAS, see edit.